# osmdata - getbb not downloading entire dataset

Tags: r, openstreetmap

I am trying to get all postal code data for Bratislava, SK city using package `osmdata`. I checked and they should be filled for all city districts, however with `getbb()` I am getting only a subset. Any hints on what is wrong?

My code:

```r
library(osmdata)

getbb(place_name = "Bratislava") |> 
    opq() |>
    add_osm_feature(key = 'boundary', value = 'postal_code',
                    value_exact = F, key_exact = F) |>
    osmdata_sf()
```

With this I get 35 entries, but I am missing for example postal code 831 01, which is available when I check on [OSM direct](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/1081848174).

Also I checked on the map and missing postal code is within generated BB.

Comment: Please let us know what package `getbb` is from ... ?? (and the other functions you're using ...)

Comment: I am using osmdata package for R https://github.com/ropensci/osmdata

Comment: I'm not familiar with R. However, you are looking for elements with the tag `boundary=postal_code` whereas your example node has the tag `postal_code=831 01`. These are two different tags. The boundary tag is usually used on *relations* whereas your example is a *node*. I suspect there is no postal code relation for `831 01` yet in OSM. That's why the result won't include your node, despite of the postal code tag. You can try to add the missing boundary relation to OSM if you have a good data source with a compatible license.